# How can i achieve this with JQuery

Tags: jquery, href, addclass

I currently have this in my document

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("[href$='.html']").addClass('html');
     $("[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
});
```

which styles any links that have an html extension and pdf extension. If the url has the extension it displays an image before the link. I want to make it only style those in an unordered list I have with a class of "dlist." How can I do this? I tried adding it before the [href] but nothing happened. Problem I'm having is it's styling other links in articles and not only the download section like I need it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("ul.dlist a[href$='.html']").addClass('html');
     $("ul.dlist a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
});
```

You'll need a space between `ul.dlist` and `a[href$='.pdf']`.

The space is the [`descendant-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Also, you'll notice that I added `a` before the `[href...]` selector. This will be more efficient because it will not need to analyze *all* elements, but rather just the `a` elements.

Comment: ...nine seconds? Agh! One day I'll learn: **answer**, then **edit**, the question! XD +1 for being first, and for having the same answer as myself (albeit with further explanation edited in afterwards). =)

Comment: @David: Yeah, I learned that long ago from the great ones. ;o)

Comment: Ah, well: on the bright side, though, if you get another three up-votes, and accepted, I think I at least qualify for some kind of badge? =)

Comment: @David: Hmmm... I'm not aware of that badge, but I'll pull for you anyway. :o)

Comment: Oh, it's one of those half-remembered things that I think I read while I was still, at least, half asleep one morning...but thanks! :D

Comment: sweet, thanks alot havent tried it but know it will work i tried it without adding the "a" which was dumb of me.

Comment: @josh: It will work without the `a`, but it's less efficient. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: i tried it before without an   a   and it didn't work, but i was testing it on a live version using Firefox so it might have cached the page so i wasn't seeing any difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul.dist [href$='.html']").addClass('html');
   $("ul.dist [href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.dlist a[href$='.html']").addClass('html');
    $("ul.dlist a[href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding .dlist seems to work for me
[jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/Fs8QB/)

```
$(".dlist [href$='.html']").addClass('html');
$(".dlist [href$='.pdf']").addClass('pdf');
```